# msi created in cx_freeze does not install program

Tags: python, windows-installer, cx-freeze

I have a python program I've created and turned into an exe with cx_freeze.  When just creating the exe with "python setup.py build", everything works great.  Now I am trying to create an installer for it by using "python setup.py bdist_msi" and everything seems to work great at first.

The installer pops up and asks me to select a directory.  After clicking next, Windows requires me to accept that I'm installing from an unknown publisher.  After accepting, the next page immediately jumps to "Completing the (program) installer", and "click finish to exit the installer".  After clicking finish, I cannot find my program file anywhere, and the installer appeared to do nothing.

I've tried running this on multiple computers, and nothing seems to work.  I think this is an issue with my setup.py script.  This does include several qml files and some pictures in my "Resources" folder, and there are several csv's in my "Data-and-executable" folder, plus a exe that is called on by my python script.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


# dependencies
build_exe_options = {
    "packages": ['atexit', "os", "sys", "csv", "time", "functools", "PySide2.QtCore", "PySide2.QtWidgets", "PySide2.QtUiTools", "PySide2.QtQuick", "PySide2.QtQml", "PySide2.QtGui", "shiboken2"],


"include_files": ['README.md', r'Resources','inputClass.py', 'selections.py','simulationOutput.py',
                  'Data-and-executable'], 
                  "include_msvcr": True,
                  "excludes": ["Tkinter", "Tkconstants", "tcl", ],
                  "build_exe": "build",

                     }

bdist_msi_options = {
    'add_to_path': False,
    'initial_target_dir': r'[ProgramFilesFolder]\%s\%s' % ("Name", "Product"),
                    }

executable = [
    Executable("main.py",
               base="Win32GUI",
               targetName="product.exe",
               icon= r"Resources\logo_icon.ico"
               )
             ]


setup(name = "Product",
      version = "0.3",
      description = "Simulator",
      options={"bdist_msi": bdist_msi_options,
               "build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables=executable
     )
```

There are no error messages or anything else to tip me off as to what's going on.  Even calling my .msi with cmd does not provide any insight.

Comment: Create a full verbose log like this: `msiexec -i setup.msi -l*vx log.txt`

Comment: I ran that code in the console, except I changed "setup" to my .msi file name.  When I did that, all that popped up was a window with a display message beginning with "Windows ® Installer. V 5.0.17763.404 

msiexec /Option <Required Parameter> [Optional Parameter]"

Comment: This command works. Using it regularly. Do you have spaces in the name of the .msi or log file name? Then you have to quote like "my setup.msi".

Comment: Wow, bad miss by me.  I'll dig through this log to try to figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

Smh.  I had all of my files just in the "build" folder, and not the "build/exe.win-amd64-3.6" folder. It works.